# While running angular2 tests on the all app, global function tests are failing because the global function is undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

First, let me say that tests are passing when i'm executing them only in the sub-folder, using in *test.ts* :

```
.then(() => require.context('./app/folder/where/tests/fail/later', true, /\.spec\.ts/))
```

I am using angular-cli to launch tests through '*ng test (--code-coverage, sometimes...)*'

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.9.4
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9
```

---

The thing is:
When I'm running all the tests together, tests on the following file are failing.

*error.helper.ts*

```
export function formatErrorStatusCode(code: number): any{
  if ([0, 401, 403, 404, 408, 409, 502, 503].indexOf(code) != -1) {
    return code;
  } else {
    switch (code.toString()[0]) {
      case  ('3') :
        return '3XX';
      case  ('4') :
        return '4XX';
      case  ('5') :
        return '5XX';
      default :
        return 'BAD';
    }
  }
}
```

*error.helper.spec.ts    <= just un extract, other tests are similar, like the failing messages.*

```
import {formatErrorStatusCode} from "../../shared/helpers/error.helper";

describe('CategoryComponent', () => {
  it('should return the code BAD if it is a unknown error', () => {
    expect(formatErrorStatusCode(800)).toBe('BAD');
  });
});
```

And I have the following result in the console:

```
Firefox 52.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.11.0) ErrorHelper should return the code BAD if it is a unknown error FAILED
    Expected undefined to be 'BAD'.
    @webpack:///src/app/shared/helpers/error.helper.spec.ts:33:4 <- src/test.ts:40231:9 [ProxyZone]
    ProxyZoneSpec.prototype.onInvoke@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:114510:20 [ProxyZone]
    Zone.prototype.run@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- src/test.ts:112174:24 [<root> => ProxyZone]
    wrapTestInZone/<@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- src/test.ts:114225:20 [<root>]
    ZoneQueueRunner.prototype.execute@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:132:0 <- src/test.ts:114255:17 [<root>]
    Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:0 <- src/test.ts:112212:28 [<root> => <root>]
    drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:418:0 <- src/test.ts:112479:25 [<root>]
```

And the function formatErrorStatusCode(X) is never called.

I do not have any idea where it is coming from: angular2? angular-cli? jasmin? karma? a mix of all? is it because i have too many tests running (287)? Or something else...

If some of you have some pistes, i would appreciate them.

thx

Comment: It seems you have some kind of dependency between your tests. You can try to gradually exclude tests one by one or folder by folder until tests stop fail